# JSF MySQL Enum type

Tags: mysql, jsf, enums

I have a MySQL database with a table, in that table i have an Enum column that looks like this:

```
enum('mmol/l','pmol/l','g/l','mmol/mol','cm','kg','st','l','mg/l','mg/mmol',
     'micromol/l','ml/min','poäng','%','mm Hg','JDF enheter','ak-index')
```

I have a textfield there the user write in one of the values above and i can insert and take out data to this column with out problem if a user write the string right.

But it's no guarantee that the user know what enum values you can write in this field, so is that anyway to take out what enum values you can write to the database, or do i need to hardcode it?

Comment: why are you using textbox. you need to use listbox.

Comment: to use a listbox i need to take out the values for the enum

Comment: Why exactly is that a problem? Simply showing all available enum values in a listbox is exactly the answer to your problem. How else would you provide the enduser the valid options to choose from?

Comment: Please read the whole question. That exactly what i want but I dont know how to take out the values that the column accept and list it in a listbox... See the last sentence in my question

Comment: Just build a **HashMap<Integer,String>** using the enumeration column values (parse it manually if necessary), then you will be able to use this HashMap to build a **h:selectOneMenu** in the jsf page and use its value to recover the id of the selected option. Regards,

Comment: the problem is the parsing part. Now im using a h:selectOneMenu with a String array with the enums, its work fine. But I'm afraid the enum values in the column to be changed so i dont want to hardcode it, do you know any link where I can see an example of parsing enum columns?

Comment: If you don't want use parsing, you can use ***HashMap<String,String>*** -- first key, second value.. you havn't any obligate to use Integer as a key of map